# The server response was: 4.7.0 Temporary server error in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, data-warehouse, ssis-2012, msbi

I am getting an error when I schedule a SSIS package in SQL server job 
but if run manually the package as well as job also executing successfully.
Even if I am creating the package in same server where data present in the database.

But when it is running via scheduler I am getting this error

> Executed as user: NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 13.0.1601.5 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft. All rights reserved.    Started:  11:00:00 PM  Error: 2019-05-09 23:00:22.74     Code: 0xC002F304     Source: Send Mail Task Send Mail Task     Description: An error occurred with the following error message: "Error in processing. The server response was: 4.7.0 Temporary server error. Please try again later. PRX5 ".  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  11:00:00 PM  Finished: 11:00:22 PM  Elapsed:  21.859 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.

Comment: Is the package on the job running under the same credentials as it is manually?